# Missing OTA Library in Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: vba, excel, alm

I have written a VBA Macro in Excel 2010 for running ALM Test Cases from Test Set using VBA Macro Button Click Functionality.
Below Addins were selected in Excel 2010 Tools References Menu.

1. Visual Basic For Applications
2. OLE Automation
3. Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library
4. OTA Com Type Library

Opening the Same Macro in Excel 2016 gives me Compatible Version Error. Also Its showing Missing OTA Com Type Library in References Tools Menu.
There is no OTA Com Type Library in the Dropdown Menu of Tools References.

Steps I have performed so far:

1. I have checked Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library Add-in. Don't know what other Add-ins are required.
2. Installed Microsoft Excel Add-In for ALM 12.2x and 12.5x from HP_ALM Help Site

[image]

Comment: Do you have Excel 2010 & 2016 on the same machine?

Comment: Hi Barney, No I never installed 2010 Excel

Comment: Make sure you have `HP ALM Connectivity` add-on installed on the machine from where you try to run/develop the macro.

Comment: Thanks Barney, Steps I perform below:-
 1. Go to ALM Client Link and click on Tools and then download HP ALM Connectivity and install it.
 2. Then I again opened the Macro and OTA Com Type Library is visible to me. I checked and set it to Priority to High. 
Thanks. I can mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use HP OTA, it is important to have the HP ALM Connectivity add-on installed on the machine from where you try to run/develop your code.

Steps to get the ALM Connectivity Tool.

1. ALM_SERVER/qcbin/
2. Click "Tools"
3. HP ALM Connectivity  "Enables you to integrate HP ALM with other tools."

Source:
http://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.50/online_help/Content/addins_index.htm?Highlight=OTA